# How do I redirect to a page after a file download has been initiated with mod_rewrite?

Tags: mod-rewrite, download

Just as the title states. Say an individual accesses a file from my database, http://domain.com/database/file.zip. Once that file download has been initiated, I wish the browser to be redirected to the database directory again. Here's what I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^Database(.zip)$ http://domain.com/db/index.html [R=301,L]
```

But, I get a 500 error.

And if I am being too picky, it would be nice to ignore this function on links such as: &file=something.zip.

Either way, getting the first portion to work would be fantastic.

Edit!

Here is what worked for me in the end. Cheers!

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} .*zip$|.*rar$|.*tar$|.*txt$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dl.php?url=%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really possible with mod_rewrite the way you have described: once the server has started delivering content (sent a 200 status code) there is no way to initiate a second response without a corresponding second request.

If you want to do this you'll have to do it on the client side: for example launch the download targetting a separate, hidden iframe and if the download starts then you can change the page location using `window.location`.

Comment: So, I can't do anything to the files being accessed directly? Then there's no point. Bummer.

Comment: No, only 1 result can be returned from a single request: once the server sends the 200 until you initiate another request you are done. Not sure why you're getting a 500, though. That setup should just redirect to http://leetupload.com/dbindex2/index.html on any request for *Database.zip*: perhaps remove the capturing group?

Comment: That could be. Well, instead of using htaccess, since that is not feasible, is there maybe a way to apply a banner with CGI (or something) above any file found within the database? I just want some way to benefit from all of the bandwidth leaching. Though, thank you for the advice so far!

Comment: You could redirect to a different page that included a download link: if you look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond one of the variables you can use in a RewriteCond is HTTP_REFERER. So you check the referer, and if its not from your site you redirect to a landing page covered in ads with a small *Download* link. When they click on that the referer will be your site and you let them go.

Comment: Haha! I like your style! So, I can redirect if it is a different referrer, and if it is to a file within the database by using them in tangent? I guess if that's the case, then I will have to come up with a way to have by indexer show a download page for each file.

Comment: Yep, you can specify 2 `RedirectCond` lines: one for the referer and one based on the request URI using a pattern that matches files in  your db. Then pass the name to a landing page script that does whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks. Let me know how the RewriteCond stuff works out for you: I've done a lot of mod_rewrite stuff in the past, but nothing down this alley so I'd be curious to see how well it works out.

Comment: Well, first I need to figure out how to make each download within the database have their own dedicated page... THEN, I'll work on this. I'll keep this page bookmarked, and let you know how it all goes!

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at my .htaccess file? I'm not sure if I wrote it correctly, seeing as it proceeds to allow for the download to occur, without a redirect.

`RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} .*zip$|.*rar$|.*tar$.*txt$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !leetupload\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /dsplus/m.php?p=$1`

Comment: Try adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f` as well (makes sure its a real file), editing the last rule to be `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dsplus/m.php?p=%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`. I'm not sure if that last one will work, but it might?

Comment: I changed those two things, but it still didn't change anything. Do I need to add in Options +FollowSymLinks ? When I do, the only thing that it lets the htaccess do, is throw a 500 internal error. Otherwise, htaccess still allows for downloads.

Comment: You're welcome. Would you mind posting the `RewriteCond` statements you used in an edit to the question? Would love to see what actually worked.

Comment: Actually, without the -f, it worked perfectly fine. So, it's basically what you decided on. It was so strange that sometimes it would work, and other times it wouldn't (it seemed quite random). Anyway, after leaving it on the server for a day, it worked well enough! Edited!